# BlockUI in javascript in grails

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails

I have made a js file for all the javascript function and processing before sending data to controller.

While I send the data to controller I need to block the UI as usual.

I have downloaded and add the `jquery.blockUI.js` to my `main.gsp`.

My javascript code is given below:

```
$.ajax({
    type:       "POST",
    dataType:   "JSON",
    url:        addConURL,
    data:       {technology:technology},
    beforeSend: function() {
      $.blockUI({ message: '<h1><img src="static/busy.gif" /> ...</h1>' });
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $.unblockUI();
        if (data != null && data != "" && data.status == "Order Created") {
          alert("Order created successfully");
        } else {
          alert("Failed");
        }
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
        $('#spinner').hide();
        alert("Failed with error::"+error);
        console.log(xhr.statusText);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(error);
    },
    cache: false
```

But,$.blockUI is not working even if I have added the jquery js and spinner image.

Please help.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide a little more information.  What does your gsp file look like?  If you open up developer mode in your browser, do all the resources get downloaded?  Does the browser report any errors?  Do you have any logging output in your controller to see if the request made it?

Comment: That is a simple jax call.From jsp,am taking a json as technology to controller.Even all the processing are being done successfully if I do not give $.blockUI({ message: '<h1><img src="static/busy.gif" /> ...</h1>' });..If I remove $.blockUI all the processing starts as usual.COntrol is coming back,and showing the alert as success or failed.That means my application can not recognize blockUI.Why is that so?After adding all the necessary jars,why it is not working?

Comment: Something I would look at first is are the blockui js being included in the page?  Next would be to see if you get any errors reported by the developer console in your browser.  I would then add some console.log() statements before and after the blockui calls.  I don't have direct experience with blockui but those would be the steps I would take to see why it's not working.

Comment: Just a side note, if you're using bootstrap, maybe you can show a modal dialog that is not closable and then close it on success.  Also I'd change the options on the ajax call to not be async.

Comment: Error in console is::ReferenceError: $ is not defined addCon.js:4 ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.blockUI.js:616

Comment: After putting console.log() before and after blockUI call,error is:  TypeError: $.blockUI is not a function addCon.js:207
"before" is coming before blockUI() call,not after log.

Comment: In the index page I have added the js like <g:javascript src="jquery.blockUI.js" /> and calling custom js like <g:javascript src="addCon.js" />.

Comment: In your console see what resources were fetched i.e jquery.js...You should see a resource for blockui.  If you don't, try change the inclusing of blockui to as follows:    <script src='<g:resource dir="/js" file="blockui.js"/>'><script>  Change the parameters accordingly to where your stuff is.  My suspicion is blockui isn't getting loaded by the browser.